# Extremely grainy render

Tags: rendering

I am trying to create an under water scene but it is not turning out like the tutorial I am following. My main issue is when I come to rendering the image it is extremely grainy and I cant get it to look realistic. Would someone be able to help me with this problem and explain in really basic terms as I have no other experience with these kind of projects. Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: Have you read any of the related links to the right, or searched "grainy cycles"?

Comment: Try disabling caustics (reflective and refractive) in the render settings.

Answer (score 0):

Its a viewport render preview at 32 samples.
No wonder its grainy.
Increase the samples.
With glass materials try at least 1000.